# What term do you use for manual database changes?

Tags: sql

The company I am working for calls manual database changes (ie., writing a SQL update/insert/delete) a "data hammer".  While the term makes sense, I have yet to find any other organization or group that calls it by this name.  A search here on SO yields no results.

How do you refer to manual database changes?  Is there a standard term?

Comment: If a simple UPDATE is a "data hammer", how do you call manual changes by stored procedures?

Answer (score 2):

I usually hear it referred to as 'writing a query' or 'updating a query'.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, if I delete all the rows I call it "*blatting*" the database.  If I manually force data into it then (just in my head) I call it "*shoe-horning*" the data into the database.

I think I need a cool term for updating it though.  I used to say I was munging it, but that's been stolen by the deployment applications meaning token replacement, so I need a new term, otherwise I'm in danger of being understood outside my organisation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a professional term for this. We just call it "manual database change".

Answer (score 0):

How about calling it "hacking" the database?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Back-end changes. This is of course different from backside changes, which are what happen when you spend 8-10hrs a day in an Aeron.

Answer (score 0):

"Ad-hoc query" is sometimes used. As opposed to a stored procedure.